# Atribuir texto em arquivo TXT para uma variável

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

Bom dia!

Estou rodando um projeto que está funcionando normalmente, mas gostaria de automatizá-lo mais para ganhar tempo na operação.
No caso meu projeto pega em um arquivo de texto as principais palavras que eu descrevi dentro da variável **"word"** e coloca para mim no final de cada frase do aquivo de texto caso encontre alguma palavra.

Porem as variáveis do **word** estou escrevendo dentro do código e gostaria de transforma-la em um arquivo de .txt também e assim consigo fazer um loop dentro do projeto pois são 21 projetos diferentes.

Projeto que esta rodando normalmente:

```
    arquivo2 = open(r'\Texto para a\Vers2.txt', 'w')

with open(r'\Respostas.txt') as stream:


    for line in stream:
        for word in ['(3)produto', 
'/PRODUTOS', 
'ATENDIMENTOPRODUTOS', 
'PRODUTO', 
'produto!', 
'Produto,', 
'produto.', 
'produto?', 
'PRODUTOR', 
'PRODUTOS', 
'produtos!', 
'produtos!!', 
'produtos,', 
'produtos.', 
'produtos...', 
'PRODUTOS/SERVIOS', 
'produtos;', 
'PRODUTOSDEVERIA', 
'PRODUTOSPIC', 
'PRODUTOSQUE', 
'COBRAR', 
'autro']:
            if word.lower() in line.lower():

              a = (line.strip(), '¬', word + '\n\r')

              arquivo2.writelines(a)                         

              break

arquivo2.close()
```

Esta parte a partir dos [] que gostaria de transformar em arquivo.
Ja tentei algumas soluções que vi aqui no site mas nenhuma funcionou. Conseguem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crie um arquivo chamado palavras.txt contendo as palavras:

```
(3)produto 
/PRODUTOS 
ATENDIMENTOPRODUTOS 
PRODUTO 
produto! 
Produto 
produto.
```

Efetue a leitura do mesmo e guarde os valores em uma lista

```
with open('palavras.txt','r') as arq:
     palavras = arq.readlines()
```

pronto agora efetue o laço *for* na lista *palavras* para comparar com o texto que procura

```
for line in stream:
    for word in palavras:
```

Não se esqueça de efetuar o tratamento para as quebras de linha *\n* do seu arquivo palavras.txt na hora de efetuar a comparação entre os valores

Comment: Perfeito Willian! funcionou muito bem, muito obrigado!